# python zero division error. float division by zero. simple script

Tags: python, arrays, error-handling

I am trying to convert an array into a percent change array. it is simple, but I do not know why I am getting a zero division error. I tried putting

```
from __future__ import division
```

at the top of my file, but no dice.

my code:

```
def convert(anarr):
     x = 1
    while(x < len(anarr)):
        anarr[x] = (anarr[1] - anarr[x])/anarr[1]
        x += 1
    print anarr
```

main:

```
>>>
>>>
>>> myarr = [20130101.0,34.75,34.66,34.6,34.6,34.61,34.65,34.69]
>>> convert(myarr)
>>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#10>", line 1, in <module>
    convert(myarr)
  File "C:\Users\viral\Desktop\python\mapping.py", line 38, in convert
    anarr[x] = (anarr[1] - anarr[x])/anarr[1]
ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are modifying the array as you go, one of the elements is becoming 0 which causes the error. There are consecutive 34.6s in the array which have a percentage change of 0. Put the changes to a new array, and copy later if you want.

Comment: OK. If that's helpful, please accept my answer. Any questions, just ask me.

Answer (score 1):

After anarr[x] = (anarr[1] - anarr[x])/anarr[1] works first time, anarr[1] becomes 0.

So, This is not a bug. Your definition of function convert does it just like this.